# How to calculate variance of prediction of a statistical forecasting model?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, regression

I have a forecasting model $f$ that gives me my estimate $\hat{y}$. I also have the actual values $y$ that happened so I can compare how my model would have done out of sample.

Now the problem I have is that my model is giving me a point estimate -- one scalar value $\hat{y}$. However I think of my prediction as a normally distributed random variable, sometimes the variance is small and the model really will give a value close to the real one $y$, sometimes the uncertainty increases and so does the variance.

The closest intuitively I can get to this is to think that my expectation $\mu$ is $\hat{y}$ and that my $$\hat{\sigma} = \langle|\mathbf{\hat{y}} - \mathbf{y} | \rangle$$ i.e. average absolute error, but that does not seem right.

One approach I quite liked for uncertainty quantification was:
$$\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{\bigg\langle (\mathbf{\hat{y}} - \langle \mathbf{y} \rangle)^{2} \bigg\rangle + \langle|\mathbf{\hat{y}} - \mathbf{y} | \rangle^{2}}$$ but I am uncertain about its mathematical basis.

Comment: Are the tilted brackets inner products? What kind?

Comment: @tintinthong No -- they represent an average $\langle \square \rangle = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\big( \square \big)$.

Comment: Ahh so you are making measures of uncertainty (not necessarily the consistent estimate of the variance)  up to fit your interpretation that it sometimes has "small variance" and it sometimes has "large variance". So at each time step the normal distribution you sample your predictions from has a different variance?

Comment: I am not too sure what your model is but time series data are frequently analysed using kalman filters. The essence is that there is a state equation(usually a random walk of some value $x$) and a measurement equation(some normal relationship with the data $y$). The state equation is able to make predictions  $\hat{y}$ and the best estimate of $x$ is then an update of the prediction $\hat{y}$. The good thing about this in your context is that agreement between $y$ and $\hat{y}$ can be weighed by the an ongoing estimate of the variance of both the state equation and measurement equation

Answer (score 0):

Consistent estimator of the variance of some random variable $Y$ (regardless of its distribution. Namely, as long as $E|Y|^2< \infty$ and $EY=\mu$ and $var(Y) = \sigma^2$) is 
$$
\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y}_n)^2,
$$
hence, if your variable of interest is $\hat{Y}$ then 
$$
\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{Y}}^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{y}_i - \bar{\hat{y}}_n)^2,
$$
where in linear regression with an intercept term you have $\bar{\hat{y}}_n = \bar{y}_n$.

Comment: Well, this is my "intuitive" variance then or the MSE. But you are calling it "prediction error" variance (which looks more like an expectation/average of it), whereas I am after the variance of the prediction $\hat{y}$ value. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I've edited the answer

Comment: I see what you are showing, but unfortunately it just does not capture my problem. The prediction $\hat{y}$ does not have a stationary distribution -- it changes. At one time step the model might be really confident about the prediction (low variance) and in other not (high variance) -- I just do not know how to capture that mathematically.